# Are Hankel functions linearly independent for all $m$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Are Hankel functions linearly independent for all real $m$? 
For $m \in Z$ , $J_m (x)$ and $Y_m (x)$ form a pair of linearly independent equations.

If $m$ is real and $m \not \in Z$ then solutions is given by $J_m (x)$ and $J_{-m} (x)$.

It's easy to find a reference for above statements. It surprisingly hard to find any article or book where independence of first and second Hankel functions is stated explicitly for all $m$. Are they independent for all real $m$? Could you kindly provide a reference for that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear independence over $\mathbb{C}$ of $H^{(1)}_\nu(z)$ and $H^{(2)}_\nu(z)$ follows from linear independence of $J_\nu(z)$ and $Y_\nu(z)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, since $H^{(1)}_\nu(z) = J_\nu(z) + iY_\nu(z)$ and $H^{(2)}_\nu(z) = J_\nu(z) - iY_\nu(z)$ (see [1] section 3.6).

Indeed given $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $c_1H^{(1)}_\nu(z) + c_2H^{(2)}_\nu(z) = 0$, we have $(c_1 + c_2)J_\nu(z) + i(c_1 - c_2)Y_\nu(z) = 0$.

By linear independence of $J_\nu(z)$ and $Y_\nu(z)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ we have $c_1 + c_2 = 0$ and $i(c_1 - c_2) = 0$, which means $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, as required.

---

Now to show that $J_\nu(z)$ and $Y_\nu(z)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$ for any $\nu \in \mathbb{C}$.

When $\nu \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, the Neumann functions are defined by $$Y_\nu(z) = \frac{J_\nu(z)\cos(\nu\pi) - J_{-\nu}(z)}{\sin(\nu\pi)}$$
and for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, we define $$Y_n(z) = \lim\limits_{\nu\to n}\frac{J_\nu(z)\cos(\nu\pi) - J_{-\nu}(z)}{\sin(\nu\pi)}$$ (see [1] section 3.54).

For any $\nu \in \mathbb{C}$, the Wronskian of $J_\nu$ and $J_{-\nu}$ is $W[J_\nu(z), J_{-\nu}(z)] = -\frac{2\sin(\nu\pi)}{\pi z}$ (see [1] section 3.12).

Then when $\nu \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, the Wronskian of $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ is easily computed to be (by linearity of the Wronskian with respect to second argument, and using the definition for $Y_\nu$ above) $$W[J_\nu(z), Y_\nu(z)] = \frac{2}{\pi z}$$ and the result also holds when $\nu$ is an integer by continuity (see [1] section 3.63).

Hence $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ are also linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$.

It is also possible to show that $H^{(1)}_\nu(z)$ and $H^{(2)}_\nu(z)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$ for any $\nu$ by computing the Wronskian $$W[H^{(1)}_\nu(z), H^{(2)}_\nu(z)] = -\frac{4i}{\pi z}$$ (see [1] section 3.63).

[1] *Watson, G. N.*, [**A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions.**](http://www.hti.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=umhistmath;idno=ACV1415), Cambridge: University Press, viii, 804 S. (1922). [ZBL48.0412.02](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:48.0412.02).).

Comment: But $J_m$ and $Y_m$ are not independent when $m \not \in Z$.

Comment: They are always linearly independent. See *A treatise on the theory of Bessel functions* by G.N. Watson for a reference. He shows that $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ are linearly independent by computing the Wronskian in section (3.63. *Fundamental systems of solutions to Bessel's equation*). The function $Y_\nu$ is defined in (3.54. *The Weber-Schläfli function of the second kind*). Also see section (3.12 *A fundamental system of solutions to Bessel's equation*) where he computes the Wronskian of $J_\nu$ and $J_{-\nu}$ and shows they are linearly independent for $\nu \not\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The Hankel functions $H^{(1)}_\nu$ and $H^{(2)}_\nu$ are defined in section (3.6. *Functions of the third kind*).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it mean that in the links below there is a mistake?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_second_kind:_Y%CE%B1
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselDifferentialEquation.html

In the above links, authors suggest that depending on $m$ we have two different solutions. I assumed that's due to dependence of $Y_m (x)$ and $J_m(x)$ when $m \not \in Z$. Could you please shortly comment on this?

Comment: It's not really a mistake on their end, but perhaps there is some need for clarification. When $\nu$ is not an integer, the solutions $J_{\nu}$ and $J_{-\nu}$ are linearly independent, so you can use them as the two solutions of the Bessel DE. When $\nu = n$ is an integer however, $J_{-n} = (-1)^n J_n$ so they are not linearly independent. The function $Y_n$ is still linearly independent from $J_n$ as seen by computing the Wronskian. And $Y_\nu$ remains linearly independent from $J_\nu$ for *any* $\nu$ because for other $\nu$ it is a linear combination of $J_\nu$ and $J_{-\nu}$.

Comment: So in all cases you can use $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ as a fundamental set of solutions to Bessel's equation. You can also use $J_\nu$ and $J_{-\nu}$ as a fundamental set, except when $\nu$ is an integer, in which case you have to use $Y_\nu$ (which is defined as a limit in order to make this work in this case). So $(J_\nu, Y_\nu)$ is the more general pair of fundamental solutions to the Bessel DE. Note also that $J_{-\nu} = \cos(\nu\pi)J_\nu + \sin(\nu\pi)Y_\nu$, so if $J_{-\nu}$ is linearly independent from $J_\nu$, so must be $Y_\nu$.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you :).